# CURL not working when used inside a function

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to execute curl using the following code.

```
mainFunction{
  .
  .
  $url = strtolower($request->get('url', NULL));
  $html_output= $this->startURLCheck($url);
  .
  .
}

function startURLCheck($url)
{
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 $html_output = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

When i give the string URL directly this is working fine. But then I pass the string data through a function curl is not executing. curl_error gives shows no errors too. I tried many encoding and decoding method for the string with same result.Am i doing something wrong? I working using XAMPP server on windows.

I'm passing URL to this function after getting the URL from a HTML post request in another function.

Comment: $url is outside your scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php also `curl_error()` will give more enlightening info about what goes wrong in a curl call

Comment: can you add the syntax you use to define the function?

Comment: make sure your function si something like runCurl($url) { ... } and then in your code you could do runCurl('http://foo/bar');

Comment: @ Pekka : CURL_ERROR did not show any message or error number

Comment: @ManojSreekumar Does it work when you pass `http://www.google.com` as the URL variable from an HTML post request in another function?

Comment: On thing that i have noticed now is that when I print $html_output using print_r it prints "Please Wait ... Redirecting to ' and the url..but when I hardcode the URL inside the function it prints the html page content...@Antony : It is the same for http://www.google.com too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Guys I have found the problem..Finally..

When I set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION for the curl this is working fine...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

But stil it is not clear why it worked when I hardcoded the URL inside the function and did not work when I passed url as a variable into the function, without setting CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ... When I set this option it is working in both ways..

Comment: Glad you found it.  I think you might need to include more of the involved code if you want assistance regarding the hardcoded URL inside the function vs passed-in-as-argument issue.  The best thing is to write a self-contained test case that others on stackoverflow can run themselves and test.  It doesn't have to be the exact code you are dealing with, just a example that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your function startURLCheck does not actually return a value for the main program to use.  Change the last line:

```
function startURLCheck($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

In your calling code, take out the "$this->"

```
$html_output = startURLCheck($url);
```

$html_output now contains results of the curl call.

I have assumed that you copied and pasted this code from somewhere since your "mainFunction" declaration is syntactically incorrect, and you used "$this->" without specifying that startURLCheck was a method of an object.

If in fact you intend startURLCheck to be an object method and you want it to set $html_output on the object, do this:

```
<?php

class Example {
    private $html_output;

    function mainFunction()
    { 
        $url='http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-iPhone-5-16GB-Black-Slate-Cricket-intl-UNLOCKED-pleeze-read-ad-/251252227033';
        $this->startURLCheck($url);
        echo "HTML output: " . $this->html_output;
    }

    function startURLCheck($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        $this->html_output = curl_exec($ch);
    }
}

$example = new Example();
$example->mainFunction();
```

I have tested this code on the command line (not in a web page).  If you copy and paste this into a file and run it using php -r you will see the results.  (And note that I didn't include a closing ?> tag.  The closing tag is optional when the file contains only PHP code and no HTML.  In fact it is recommended that the closing tag be omitted in such cases.  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

Please also note in your question code for mainFunction you have illegal spaces before "pleeze" in your URL and you are missing the semicolon at the end of the $url assignment.

Hope this helps.  Good luck.

Comment: On thing that i have noticed now is that when I print $html_output using print_r it prints "Please Wait ... Redirecting to ' and the url..but when I hardcode the URL inside the function it prints the html page content...I'm sorry about the incomplete code..what i have given is the part of my function too..later I'm analysing the html_output using regex and returning another output..

Answer (score 1):

This works good.

```
<?php
function excURL()
{
 $ch = curl_init();
 $url = "http://www.google.com";
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 $html_output = curl_exec($ch);
 echo $html_output;
}

excURL();

?>
```

Comment: Yes this works for me too..But then I pass the URL through a variable into the function it is not working